# PHP and MySQL: Downloading all MLS Property Data with Rets - Bandwidth Issues

Tags: php, rets

I've been working with the Rets system (specifically PHRets) for a while now and just recently started doing nightly downloads of data to store all the properties on my database, but after only three days I'm pushing 9GB's of bandwidth usage (I'm only allotted 100GB). Is there a way to optimize my downloading and whatnot so that I don't kill my bandwidth halfway through the month?

If you could just give basic steps or tips, I'll make it happen in my code.

EX: Link up to RETS, query all data, etc, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean something like Rsync does where it only downloads new/altered data?

Comment: I currently only download new/altered data by comparing the last modification date on the databases, but it's still killing my resources.

Do things like compact downloads and bulk sql inserts help a lot?

Comment: Exporting it as compressed  SQL is obviously better for bandwidth. I'm really not sure what you could do to improve your usage. I don't see how you can kill 9GB in 3 days. How big is your database in rows? (roughly)

Answer (score 0):

I can offer a few small tips:

- Make sure you only download updates. Query the RETS server for records that have been updated between the highest last update time in your local database and the current time. (edit: I see in your comment that you are doing this)
- Don't pull data you aren't going to use. If you aren't using properties with "Closed" status for instance, make sure you don't include them in your queries. Try to filter out every possible criteria you won't be using.
- Not sure if you're downloading images, but keep the amount per listing to an absolute minimum.
- I'm pretty sure you can reduce the download frequency to every 48 hours. At least, that was what we were required to do with our local RETS provider.

Answer (score 0):

Useful tips:

1. Make Sure that required Field should be downloaded
2. Make sure you only download updates. Query the RETS server
3. If Have only Specific status Data Then Filter i.e
   Active,Contigient)
4. If MLS Support 3rd party URL then don't download Images as `GetObject`
   in PHRTES

Answer (score 0):

### Helpful Tips RETS Data Downloading

-Intial setup You need to download Full data With Photo and XML Download
-Daily based Download Update Only.
Make sure you only download updates. Query the RETS server for records that have been updated (PROP_LAST_UPDATEDATE=2-2-2012T00:00+) and Same Download Photo Download Query

-Try to implement Keeplist concept and Update status and Data

Not sure if you're downloading images, but keep the amount per listing to an absolute minimum.